# ES highlight not showing in results

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight

Can somebody tell me why these fields will not show up in my ES results (within the `highlight object`) in Sense when I know some of the sites I'm indexing into ES have content for these particular HTML elements?

ES mapping  of the fields

```
"metatag.description": {
    "type": "multi_field",
      "fields": {
        "metatag.description": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "include_in_all": false
        },
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "string",
          "index_analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
        }
      }
  },
  "metatag.keywords": {
    "type": "multi_field",
      "fields": {
        "metatag.keywords": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "include_in_all": false
        },
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "string",
          "index_analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
      }
    }
  },
```

For some reason only "title.autocomplete" is in the results?

This is my query:

```
    GET /hugetestindex/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": {
        "query": "ford mu",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "title.autocomplete": {
        "pre_tags" : ["<em>"],
        "post_tags" : ["</em>"],
        "number_of_fragments": 10,
        "fragment_size": 300
      },
      "metatags.keywords.autocomplete": {
        "pre_tags" : ["<em>"],
        "post_tags" : ["</em>"],
        "number_of_fragments": 10,
        "fragment_size": 300
      },
      "metatags.description.autocomplete": {
        "pre_tags" : ["<em>"],
        "post_tags" : ["</em>"],
        "number_of_fragments": 10,
        "fragment_size": 300
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Typo? You have `metatags` in there and it should be `metatag` (singular)?

Comment: @AndreiStefan, thank you! Needed fresh eyes on this one